# Split one row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, split

How can I get several rows from one row?

The query runs in Spark SQL.

**Input:**

The table only has one column.

```
A|BB|C
```

**Output:**

```
A
BB
C
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string functions.)

Comment: I write in Spark SQL. Actually I'm not sure if Spark SQL is a specific dbms.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I figure that out.

There is a function lateral view.

```
Select t from table_name
Lateral View Explode(split(col_name,'[|]')) as t order by t
```